# I want to write out latex code for degree of freedom of unequal variance for two samples hypothesis test

Tags: math-mode

[image][image]

I have problem writing latex code for the attach. Number one is what I want to produce and but what can produce is Number two. Please how can I include the brackets to produce Number one. The picture of Number one is attached below .

Code for Number one is given below:
NUMBER ONE:

> `$df=\frac{\left(\frac{(s_{1}^{2}{n_1}}+\frac{s_{2}^{2}{n_2-1}}\right)}{{\frac{\frac{\left(s_{1}^{2}\right)^2}{n_1}}{n_1-1}+\frac{\frac{\left(s_{2}^{2}}{n_2}\right)^2{n_2-1}}}}$`
>   but the are errors in this code.

Code for Number two are as following:
NUMBER TWO:

> `$df=\frac{\frac{s_{1}^{2}}{n_1}+\frac{s_{_2}^{2}}{n_2}}{\frac{\frac{s_{1}^{2}}{n_1}}{n_1-1}+\frac{\frac{s_{2}^{2}}{n_2}}{n_2-1}}$\\`
>       but this is not what I want. I want to product Number one formula.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code compiles fine, what is your problem?

Comment: If you want to enclose parts of your equation into brackets, maybe `\left(` and `\right)` might give you the desired result.

Comment: Your code doesn't feature any brackets (or parentheses). Hence, it's not clear what you mean by "fixing brackets".

Comment: `s_{_2}^{2}` looks wrong you have a subscript 2 n an empty base. Did you intend `s_{2}^{2}` ?

Answer (score 4):

The picture can be reproduced as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
df=
\frac{
  \left(\dfrac{s_{1}^{2}}{n_1}+\dfrac{s_{2}^{2}}{n_2}\right)^{\!2}
}{
  \dfrac{(s_{1}^{2}/n^{}_1)^2}{n_1-1}+
  \dfrac{(s_{2}^{2}/n^{}_2)^2}{n_2-1}
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Subtle points:

- `^{\!2}` will push the exponent a bit towards the large parenthesis;
- empty superscripts `^{}` make the subscripts to the *n* in the upper floor of the denominator align with those of *s*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't very clear but I suggest using display math so it is not so cramped, and have fixed the `s_{_` whch was mis-placing the subscript in one clause.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$df=\frac{\frac{s_{1}^{2}}{n_1}+\frac{s_{_2}^{2}}{n_2}}{\frac{\frac{s_{1}^{2}}{n_1}}{n_1-1}+\frac{\frac{s_{2}^{2}}{n_2}}{n_2-1}}$

use display math and no double \_, never end a paragraph with \verb|\\|

zzz
\[
df=\frac{\frac{s_{1}^{2}}{n_1}+\frac{s_{2}^{2}}{n_2}}{\frac{\frac{s_{1}^{2}}{n_1}}{n_1-1}+\frac{\frac{s_{2}^{2}}{n_2}}{n_2-1}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was the code I have with brackets but I was having error message. $df=\frac{\left(\frac{(s_{1}^{2}{n_1}}+\frac{s_{2}^{2}{n_2-1}}\right)}{{\frac{\frac{\left(s_{1}^{2}\right)^2}{n_1}}{n_1-1}+\frac{\frac{\left(s_{2}^{2}}{n_2}\right)^2{n_2-1}}}}$

Comment: @MfonEkpenyong If asking about an error you should always make a complete document (as in this answer) that makes the error and show the exact error message that you get, however the error there is in your last term `\frac{\left(s_{2}^{2}}{n_2}\right)`  has the `\left` in the numerator of the fraction but the `\right`  is outside. No one could possibly guess  you had made that error from the question as you posted it.